# Column Formatting in SQL*Plus Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I am having issues in querying from a table. As shown below, the information from a table splits in two. How can I format it so that it appears as one table, or how can i set is as default?
Thanks

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Sat Sep 8 15:00:01 2018

```
Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 CUSTOMER#                                 NOT NULL NUMBER(4)
 LASTNAME                                  NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10)
 FIRSTNAME                                 NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10)
 ADDRESS                                            VARCHAR2(20)
 CITY                                               VARCHAR2(12)
 STATE                                              VARCHAR2(2)
 ZIP                                                VARCHAR2(5)
 REFERRED                                           NUMBER(4)
 REGION                                             CHAR(2)

SQL> SELECT lastname || ', ' || lastname AS Name, address, city||', '||state AS Location
  2  from customers;

NAME                   ADDRESS              LOCATION
---------------------- -------------------- ----------------
MORALES, MORALES       P.O. BOX 651         EASTPOINT, FL
THOMPSON, THOMPSON     P.O. BOX 9835        SANTA MONICA, CA
SMITH, SMITH           P.O. BOX 66          TALLAHASSEE, FL
PIERSON, PIERSON       69821 SOUTH AVENUE   BOISE, ID
GIRARD, GIRARD         P.O. BOX 851         SEATTLE, WA
CRUZ, CRUZ             82 DIRT ROAD         ALBANY, NY
GIANA, GIANA           9153 MAIN STREET     AUSTIN, TX
JONES, JONES           P.O. BOX 137         CHEYENNE, WY
PEREZ, PEREZ           P.O. BOX 8564        BURBANK, CA
LUCAS, LUCAS           114 EAST SAVANNAH    ATLANTA, GA
MCGOVERN, MCGOVERN     P.O. BOX 18          CHICAGO, IL

NAME                   ADDRESS              LOCATION
---------------------- -------------------- ----------------
MCKENZIE, MCKENZIE     P.O. BOX 971         BOSTON, MA
NGUYEN, NGUYEN         357 WHITE EAGLE AVE. CLERMONT, FL
LEE, LEE               P.O. BOX 2947        CODY, WY
SCHELL, SCHELL         P.O. BOX 677         MIAMI, FL
DAUM, DAUM             9851231 LONG ROAD    BURBANK, CA
NELSON, NELSON         P.O. BOX 563         KALMAZOO, MI
MONTIASA, MONTIASA     1008 GRAND AVENUE    MACON, GA
SMITH, SMITH           P.O. BOX 1151        MORRISTOWN, NJ
FALAH, FALAH           P.O. BOX 335         TRENTON, NJ

20 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can control this via the `pagesize` setting:

```
SET pagesize 1000
```

You can place this command in a file called `login.sql` so that every time you open SQL*Plus from that directory it will be called.